# Possible encoding problem in PHP UDP client

Tags: php, character-encoding

I wasn't sure how to title this question. I create a UDP connection using PHP fsockopen(). I then use: `fwrite ($this->socket, "command é");` but it doesn't do anything on the server IF it has a special character in like the `é`.

I know the information I have given is vague but I am only looking to see if I should be encoding the information I send in a certain way to pass it in fwrite?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you encode the PHP in file in UTF8?

Comment: The actual .php file? I am not sure, I use netbeans editor and FTP.

Comment: I tried to rephrase your title better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is a bit unclear. You didn't talk about your server's protocol or implementation. And, you admitted that!

You rightfully suspect of your `é` character being the root cause of your problem. The only thing I could suggest you to check is the required character encoding. By default, if you write a string to a stream, it's encoded using the default system encoding, which may differ (and **does** differ if you run Windows and Linux) between nodes.

What could be happening is that your server doesn't receive `command é` but something else. You must make sure that both client and server use the same encoding, ie. UTF8.

I don't know if you have control over your server's source code, but I would suggest on the client side

```
fwrite($this->socket, utf8_encode("command é"));
```

And, on the server side, to parse the input with `utf8_decode()`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what the server is expecting and can't get much information about it. It is a gaming server that I have no control over. I tried utf8_encode and it made the command work but changed the text to something odd so not what it was expecting I guess.

Comment: "Make the command work"? So, did you fix **this** issue? Otherwise, if you don't have detailed specifications about server input (in terms of the binary encoding of commands) you are unable to fix the issue. If you had a local copy of the server, and if you are lucky enough as it logs, you could try to dig them...

Comment: It fixed the issue in the sense it showed standard ascii characters in place of the é. I will just replace the characters with something else I guess. Thanks.